# Dynamodb, query to fetch items in reverse order based on one of the parameter?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking to fetch the chat history. Now each chat message is saved as an item in the dynamodb and I want to fetch the last say 10 msgs. I am facing issue in that.
**Please see,**

I have defined my table as:

```
chatTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: Chats
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: groupId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: timestampIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: groupId
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: timestamp
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 10
              WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: groupId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            AttributeType: N
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 10
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

And I am trying to query to fetch chat history of one of the group as:

```
let getChatParams = {
      TableName: "Chats",
      IndexName: "timestampIndex",
      Limit: 10,
      ScanIndexForward: true,
      KeyConditionExpression: "groupId = :groupId",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":groupId": groupId }
    };

    let groupChat = await docClient.query(getChatParams).promise();
```

But I am getting an error,

> ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element

Can you please help what i have to do to make this query run properly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `KeyConditionExpression` you are specifying an attribute called `groupId`, but your partition key is called `id`. The Query wont work unless you specify `id`.

Comment: I changed the partion key to be groupId, but it is not fetching the items as latest first for which GSI is created. The main problem is to make "ScanIndexForward: true" work and get the latest x items from the query.

Comment: Did you change the GSI partition key as well? Please correct your question as the schema is not the one you are using and that is where your problem is.

Comment: I have updated the schema and the query in the question as per your answer. please check

Comment: GSI partition key Range is the timestamp at which the msg was sent, and i cant query based on that.